# How to create an edit form to alter the table data in MVC .NET with React

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I am quite new to MVC and React. I am trying to implement crud operations in MVC.NET with React. I am displaying a grid with a edit & delete link corresponding to each record. On clicking the edit button I am displaying a form with the corresponding data displayed in the  text fields. After performing required changes, on clicking submit button, I want the changes to be reflected for the corresponding ID.

This my grid:

[image]

Here on clicking edit button following component is displayed,

```
var Editscreen = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        debugger;
        return {

        }
    },
    render: function (data) {
const element = <div>
<p>EmployeeID
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.EmployeeID} /></p>
<br /><p>FirstName
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.FirstName} /></p>
<br /><p>LastName
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.LastName} /></p>
<br /><p>Gender
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.Gender} /></p>
<br /><p>Designation
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.Designation} /></p>
<br /><p>Salary
<br />
<input type="number" value={data.Salary} /></p>
<br /><p>City
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.City} /></p>
<br /><p>Country
<br />
<input type="text" value={data.Country} /></p>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>   
                                           </div>;


    }

});
```

will be displayed like:

[image]

On clicking "Submit" button, what is the best way to post the data to a controller method say "UpdateData". A detailed explanation with code will be very helpful. Thanks.